# pattern matching and nesting pattern matching in OCaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I have this OCaml code:

```
type primary_color = Red | Green | Blue

let r = Red

type point = float * float

type shape = 
    | Circle of {center : point; radius : float}
    | Rectangle of {lower_left : point; upper_right : point}
    
let c1 = Circle {center = (0., 0.); radius = 1.}

let r1 = Rectangle {lower_left = (-1., -1.); upper_right = (1., 1.)}


let avg a b = 
    (a +. b) /. 2.
```

and the following `center` functions that calculate the center of the different shapes:

```
(* Function one using let (...) = ... *)

let center s = 
    match s with 
    | Circle {center; radius} -> center
    | Rectangle {lower_left; upper_right} -> 
        let (x_ll, y_ll) = lower_left in
        let (x_ur, y_ur) = upper_right in 
        (avg x_ll x_ur, avg y_ll y_ur)


(* Function two using nested pattern matching Rec{ a = ..., b = ...} *)

let center s = 
    match s with 
    | Circle {center; radius} -> center
    | Rectangle {lower_left = (x_l, y_l); upper_right = (x_r, y_r)} -> 
        (avg x_l x_r, avg y_l y_r)
    | Point p -> p
```

---

I don't fully understand the way the pattern syntax is working here.
how are in the first and second functions for calculating the center the values `x_ll` and `y_ll` just handed over to the function `avg`? Because a) the pair `(x_ll, y_ll)` isn't assigned to a variable and b) the values from the Pairs are just handed over without using for example `let x_ll (a, b) = a`

Answer (score 2):

Both `center` functions are accomplishing the same thing. The first one is just being a bit more roundabout. *Though the first one doesn't match against `Point` which your earlier code doesn't define.*

If you still needed the names for the two tuples, you could use `as`.

```ml
let center s = 
    match s with 
    | Circle {center; radius} -> center
    | Rectangle {lower_left  = (x_l, y_l) as ll; 
                 upper_right = (x_r, y_r) as ur} -> 
        (avg x_l x_r, avg y_l y_r)
```

Structural pattern matching is very powerful, and it isn't limited to a certain number of levels. Consider a very simple example.

```ml
type a = {b: int}
type c = {d: a}
type e = {f: c}

let g = {f={d={b=42}}}
```

We can match directly to that `int`.

```
match g with
| {f={d={b=n}}} -> n
```

Or even leave out the `=n`.

```
match g with
| {f={d={b}}} -> b
```

We can also do this in a `let` binding.

```
let {f={d={b=n}}} = g in
n
```